# Tales of Xillia 2 - Bad End

Tags: tales-of-xillia-2

Why did they do this to us?

How do I beat the 'bad end' boss?

> You know, all of your party try to kill you and you get stun-locked and die in 5 seconds.

Are there any specific skills/artes I should use?
Is there a recommended level to be?

At the moment I just go hard at the magic users, using chromatus as soon as it's charged.

> Then about the time Gauis spawns in, I get destroyed with stuns and the inability to use items...

Answer (score 1):

i reccomend you do this on a second playtrough with a experience boost so you can be up in the higher levels at this point.
You can also consider getting the damage boost. 
I went with a Defensive strategy and defended while healing when needed, and wait for the transformation gauge to fill.
After it filled i went full offence and tried to defeat atleast 1 of them each time (tough i didn't always succeed).
however whenever the oppertunity struck i would use guard/armour break (forgot the exact name.